# Does sleep command slow the performance?

Tags: python, linux, cron, sleep

I'm using a cron task to schedule many jobs every 2 min.
Since there are no higher resolution for less than a minute in cron, I make the python code call a randomised sleep command (between 0-60) so it will spread the execution time across a minute.

This works out fine for me.

I'm just wondering that if I have a process which sleep for 50 seconds, does it keep hold of the memory during these 50 seconds? Can it cause performance problems?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 2):

Undoubtedly, whatever memory is consumed by `Python` and the startup of your script will stay in memory for the duration of the `sleep`, but since you have written the code you can organise things to minimise the memory usage until the sleep is over.

As to cpu performance, I'm sure that you will incur no overhead for the duration of the sleep.

Comment: Actually, if the OS needs that memory for something else, you can be pretty sure that the sleeping process will be swapped out before something which is in the middle of doing something. This is exactly as it should be, but might introduce a different issue if you want to be really sure it doesn't sleep for longer than you asked for. On regular consumer-grade OSes, there is no particular guarantee that things will execute at any particular time, anyway. Use a real-time OS if you really need sub-second accuracy for something.

Comment: @tripleee you should be posting this as an answer IMHO.

Answer (score 2):

At least the minimum memory of a python process will be used (if not swapped out, but swapping also slows your computer, uses disks, and should be avoided if that's a problem). Not sure if you can sleep in python before importing the needed modules.

However, you can just sleep randomly before starting your program:

```
crontab -l
* 0 * * * (sleep $((RANDOM\%50)); python program.py)
```

The `\` is needed here since just `%` otherwise means newline in cronjobs. You also might need `SHELL=/bin/bash` in the top of the crontab to make $RANDOM available. Change to `sleep $(($$\%50))` to use the PID if changing SHELL is not an option.